# Как правильно писать в файл при помощи TFile.WriteAllText

Tags: delphi

Есть вот такой код:

```
var
 Content: string;
begin
    Content := 'Привет';
    TFile.WriteAllText(OutFile, Content);
    Content := TFile.ReadAllText(OutFile);
end;
```

в результате в `Content`  находится кракозябра.

Как правильно работать с этими функциями, если вместо `Content` будут данные из другого файла, например?

Answer (score 5):

Вообще, с TFile достаточно [много проблем](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35710087/4908529), по возможности - не стоит его использовать.

Используемый вами вариант `WriteAllText` - записывает в файл, используя кодировку UTF8 (что есть хорошо), однако - не записывает [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), что есть плохо.

Как результат - `ReadAllText` пытается угадать кодировку (поскольку BOM нет) и считает ее ANSI (она идет по умолчанию). Если присутствуют только английские символы - то проблем нет, а вот другие языки действительно дадут кракозябры.

Выход из положения: указывать в явном виде кодировку либо при записи, либо при чтении:

```pascal
// при записи:
File.WriteAllText(OutFile, Content, TEncoding.UTF8); 
// в этом случае BOM будет записан и использован при ReadAllText

// или при чтении:
Content := TFile.ReadAllText(OutFile, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Какая тогда более менее адекватная альтернатива? Через TStringStream или AssignFile ? Получается что мне нудно обязательно знать в какой кодировке у меня файл?

Comment: @gregor, если файл не содержит BOM - знать кодировку нужно, т.к. многие (особенно однобайтовые) отличить друг от друга крайне сложно. Вопрос определения кодировки файла не имеет однозначного решения. `AssignFile` - имхо, постарайтесь забыть про него. С учетом того, что вы грузите содержимое файла полностью в память, не думаю что размер файла over 100Mb (грузить в память такой размер просто нецелесообразно). Я сторонник использования теплого лампового TStringList, благо у него также есть возможность задания кодировки. Но предложенный мной вариант решения тоже имеет место быть.

Comment: Я изначально использовал TStringList, но так как в файле были какие -то символы которые мешали ему загрузить весь файл, то я отказался .В файле был зашифрованный текст.по крайней мере List.Text выдавал не все

Comment: А разве TStringList не загрузит все в память?

Comment: @gregor если содержимое файла зашифровано - нельзя работать с ним, как с текстовым, поскольку зашифрованная информация может содержать (с точки зрения кодировки) некорректные/недопустимые последовательности байт, что приведет к EEncodingError (или-как-оно-там). Нужно работать именно с бинарным содержимым, благо DCPCrypt это позволяют. Да, TStringList грузит всё в память. Но и ваш код тоже это делает, поэтому я и сказал `с учетом того, что вы грузите содержимое файла полностью в память`

Comment: @gregor, как видите - детализация исходной задачи в комментариях приводит к совершенно другому решению. В вашем случае правильно было бы делать так: загрузили текст в поток (наследник `TStream`) ->зашифровали поток->записали в файл->загрузили файл в поток->расшифровали поток->записали в что-либо текстовое.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю . Направьте на мысл. Я шифрую текстовые файлы *.тхт и отдаю их пользователю. Он их должен загрузить и расшифровать для отображения . Шифрую я модулем который вы посоветовали . Как же тогда прпвильно работать ? Иногда надо иметь дело не только с файлами а просто с куском текста (string) чтобы его зашифровать

Comment: В общем работа со стримами ?

Comment: @gregor А с зашифрованными данными иначе никак. Альтернатива - AnsiString, RawByteString (в них можно запихать все, что угодно, главное понимать что это не строка в буквальном смысле, а набор байт), TBytes. На будущее - пишите вопросы применительно к реальной задаче, потому что с этим получилась задача о XYZ.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться